# Insert into DB on Sitecore Publishing

Tags: publishing

When i publish item of specific template , i would like to take the item name and Path,few more custom fields and put it on sql server (Custom Table).How do i do this please guide (This is business requirement to store it in Custom Table)

Comment: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3813/how-to-get-list-of-items-that-were-published Has several answers, including one that queries the EventQueue tables to see items recently published.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it one by one, use the `publish:itemProcessed` event. In there you can get the item that was just published and ship its properties over to your SQL server.

#### code

```
public void ItemProcessed(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var itemProcessedEventArgs = args as ItemProcessedEventArgs;

    if (itemProcessedEventArgs == null || ID.IsNullOrEmpty(itemProcessedEventArgs?.Context?.ItemId)) return;

    var db = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("web");
    var item  = db.GetItem(itemProcessedEventArgs.Context.ItemId);

    if (item == null) return;

    var model = new MyPropeerties
    {
        Path = item.Paths.FullPath,
        Name = item.Appearance.DisplayName,
        CustomField = item["MyCustomField"]
    };

    DoSomeSQLWork(model);
}

public void DoSomeSQLWork(MyPropeerties model)
{
    // Make you SQL call with your model data
}

public class MyPropeerties
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CustomField { get; set; }
}
```

#### config

```
<event name="publish:itemProcessed">
   <handler type="My.Assembly.Namespace.ItemProcessedProcessor, My.Assembly" method="ItemProcessed" />
</event>
```

Comment: This answer only duplicates https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3813/how-to-get-list-of-items-that-were-published and does not address the SQL part of the question, albeit trivial.