# How to get all the published items without publish:itemProcessed event

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-api, publishing, publishing-service

We have installed sitecore publishing service module to separate publishing. Earlier we were using `publish:itemProcessed`event to get all publishing items but with Sitecore Publish module this event is not working.

Could some one please help us here.

Comment: you can get these details from web index if you are looking to get all published items

Answer (score 2):

You need to inject your code in publishing related pipeline e.g. `publish:end` pipeline

1. Create Handler, write your code in it
2. Refer handler in config at `publish:end` event

```
<event name="publish:end">
    <handler type="namespace.classname, assembly" method="methodname" />
</event>
```

you can refer :
https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2018/01/04/sitecore-publishend-and-publishendremote/

It should solve your problem. As we also use publishing service and it works for us.

**Answer updated on 27-sept-2022** :

I have installed publishing service on my local and **Details to get all items which get published from service are given below:**

1. Article to refer for detail: https://joaoneto.blog/publishing-service-bulkpublishingend-pipeline/
2. Refer these dll to your solution
3. We need to hook into the publishEndResultBatch pipeline
   a. Add class and enter code to work with published item, e.g.

   public class PublishItemsDetail
   {

   ```
    public void Process(PublishEndResultBatchArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Aborted)
        {
            ActionForAbort(args);
        }
        else
        {
            ActionAfterPublish(args);
        }

    }
    private void ActionAfterPublish(PublishEndResultBatchArgs args)
    {
        var itemsAffected = args.Batch.Select(b => b.EntityId).Distinct().ToList();
        foreach (var item in itemsAffected)
        {
            //here you got list of all items published, now do whatever you want with this info
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }

    }
    private void ActionForAbort(PublishEndResultBatchArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("aborted publishing...");
    }
   ```

   }

b. add entry to config

```
<sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <publishEndResultBatch>
        <processor type="Nuveen.Utils.Pipelines.PublishItemsDetail, Nuveen.Utils"
                   patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Pipelines.BulkPublishingEnd.RaiseRemoteEvents, Sitecore.Publishing.Service']" >
         </processor>
      </publishEndResultBatch>
    </pipelines>
</sitecore>
```

4. Now you are all set, i have tested it on my local and it works as expected and able to get list of all published items using publish service.

Comment: Are you getting all the related items when you use publish:end event?

Comment: No, we refer it one by one for each item, to get all, you can refer : https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3813/how-to-get-list-of-items-that-were-published , see if it works for you

Comment: If we select related items from publishing dialogue box, we are getting parent items only in code but we are not getting related media and drop link items

Comment: You want me to refer Glorfindel comments ?

Comment: please tell which author comment i need to refer

Comment: you can refer Subbu comment in above stack exchange url

Comment: Subbu comment not working with Sitecore Publishing Module. Please suggest here what could be done?

Comment: I will setup it on my local first and then let you know.

Comment: @Reddy As mentioned before that i will install on my local and then will give you update, so pleasae refer updated comment for the solution you wanted. Also accept the answer if it works.

Comment: @Reddy if your question is answered then accept the answer as then it will help other users who have same requirement.